# Node.js request stream ends/stalls when piped to writable file stream

Tags: node.js, twitter, stream, pipe

I'm trying to pipe() data from Twitter's Streaming API to a file using modern Node.js Streams. I'm using a library I wrote called [TweetPipe](https://github.com/peeinears/tweet-pipe), which leverages [EventStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) and [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

Setup:

```
var TweetPipe = require('tweet-pipe')
  , fs = require('fs');

var tp = new TweetPipe(myOAuthCreds);
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./tweets.json');
```

Piping to STDOUT works and stream stays open:

```
tp.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['bieber'] })
  .pipe(tp.stringify())
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

Piping to the file writes one tweet and then the stream ends silently:

```
tp.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['bieber'] })
  .pipe(tp.stringify())
  .pipe(file);
```

Could anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say from what you have here, it sounds like the stream is getting cleaned up before you expect. This can be triggered a number of ways, see here https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/stream.js#L89-112

A stream could emit 'end', and then something just stops.

Although I doubt this is the problem, one thing that concerns me is this 
https://github.com/peeinears/tweet-pipe/blob/master/index.js#L173-174
destroy should be called *after* emitting error.

I would normally debug a problem like this by adding logging statements until I can see what is not happening right.

Can you post a script that can be run to reproduce? 
(for extra points, include a package.json that specifies the dependencies :)

Comment: Thanks, @dominic. I'll try some more logging/debugging. What's still puzzling me is why this would happen when piping to a file but not STDOUT... though I guess that suggests it could be the file stream that's emitting the 'end'. I'll put a gist together if I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Alright, I'm on to something. I'm using a through stream to filter out what types of messages get emitted: https://github.com/peeinears/tweet-pipe/blob/master/index.js#L125 . When I add a this.resume() at the end of that through stream write function, things seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-write-stream), you should create an error handler on the stream created by tp.